# mongoose is converting array to object if not specified in schema

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to save a document which has an array of objects (activity) in it. But it's getting saved as an object instead of an array.

**How I am trying to save:**

```
const User = mongoose.model('users', new mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: false}))

const user = new User({
    name: "some name",
    activity: [ {title: "activity1"} ]
})
```

**How it's getting saved:**

```
{
    name: "some name",
    activity: {
        "0": {title: "activity1"}
    }
}
```

It's happening after I upgraded mongoose to version 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug with mongoose library itself. It's happening from 5.5.1 onwards.

It's working fine after downgrading to 5.5.0 from 5.5.4.

The same is reported in github: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7733